# Como redirecionar www.subdominio.dominio.com para http://subdominio.dominio.com?

Tags: subdomínio, wildcard

Para permitir que em meu domínio/hospedagem fosse possível utilizar subdomínios dinâmicos, tive que criar um wildcard DNS (subdominio.dominio.com).

O problema é que algumas pessoas costumam acessar utilizando o prefixo '*www*' antes do subdomínio, sendo assim, se eu tentar acessar meu domínio da seguinte forma www.subdominio.dominio.com obviamente não irá resolver e irá retornar erro no navegador.

É possível configura minha hospedagem/domínio de forma que quando o usuario coloque o `www` antes do subdomínio, ele redirecione para subdominio.dominio.com? Como?

Exemplo disso é o Google Plus, se eu acessar [www.plus.google.com](http://www.plus.google.com) vai redirecionar para http://plus.google.com.

Comment: Como esta configurado o seu wildcard na zona DNS? Tenho alguns sites que usam subdomínios dinâmicos e as zonas DNS foram feitas simplesmente assim: `* 14400 IN CNAME dominio.com.br.` Acabo de testar e ele resolve quantos níveis quiser antes do domínio por ex: ´www.isso.e.um.teste.dominio.com.br´ então bastaria a regra rewrite que publicaram abaixo para funcionar...

Comment: Desculpe, eu havia configurado o wildcard com com a entrada do tipo 'A' e informei o IP errado, erro meu! Ótimo, agora está aceitando quantos níveis quiser como subdomínio.

Comment: Esta pergunta parece ser descontextualizada porque é sobre um erro especifico do usuário, que não irá auxiliar outros usuários, e parece que já foi até mesmo revolvido.

Answer (score 2):

Veja se esta regra resolve

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
```

[<sub>**Referência!**</sub>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515081/htaccess-remove-www-from-url-directories)

Comment: Não consigo testar agora pois meu domínio está em propagação, só daqui algumas horas. Mas acho que não vai resolver pois para usar o mod_rewrite, primeiro tem que tratar esse meu problema na Zona de DNS. Se eu colocar o www na frente do subdominio, vai dizer que a página não existe ou DNS não foi encontrado, após eu resolver esse problema, dai sim essa regra do mod_rewrite vai resolver, compreende?

Answer (score 0):

No seu provedor de DNS, adicione um CNAME de www.subdominio.dominio.com para subdominio.dominio.com

Comment: Tem um problema, o meu subdominio é dinâmico (WildCard DNS é um registro criado na zona de DNS que irá responder por todas as requisições de nomes de domínio não existentes, isto é, nomes de domínio para os quais não há nenhum registro.). Sendo assim, adicionando um CNAME não resolve.